# React add/remove class onScroll in Stateless component

Tags: reactjs, scroll, addclass, removeclass

How to add a class to a component when this start scrolling and then remove it when stop it in a Stateless component.

This isn't working

```
import React from 'react'

let scrollClass = 'Feed';

function handleScroll(e) {
  scrollClass = 'Feed scrolling';
}

export default function Feed(){

  return (
    <div className={scrollClass} onScroll={(e) => handleScroll(e)}>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur arcu leo. 
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the component to react to the state change you should be using [the component's state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) and to do so extend from the `React.component` baseclass. Also, as there is no such event as `onStopScroll` so you could set up a timer when the `onScroll` event occurs:

```
import React from 'react'


export default class Feed extends React.component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { scrollClass: 'Feed' }
  }

  handleScroll(e) {
    this.setState({ scrollClass: 'Feed scrolling' })
    setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ scrollCLass: 'Feed' }) }, 100)
  }

  render() {
    let { scrollClass } = this.state

    return <div className={ scrollClass } onScroll={ this.handleScroll }>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur arcu leo. 
    </div>
  }
}
```

This is illustrative, I did not run this code. Notice that I removed the parenthesis around the `<div>` and simplified the `onScroll` method injection by removing an unnecessary arrow function since you do not need the `event` object.

The logic behind this is that even if the `setTimeout` triggers the state change, every time you scroll the component's state is set again and react re-renders the elements with the new state (`scrollClass: 'Feed scrolling'`) and the cycle goes on and on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your component stateless you should have a parent component that not stateless and send an event to that from stateless component (child->parent) and the parent class component should change the state and re-render the stateless child component.